# Make actions only in the path where some specific files are found

Tags: file, search, batch-file, path, dos

I have different processes which generates log files. I want to make different actions, on the different paths where logs are stored in. I actually did this, but putting each path directly on the batch:

```
md C:\source\Process1\%date:~6,4%_%date:~3,2%_%date:~0,2%
CD /D C:\source\Process1\
for /f "skip=%1 eol=: delims=" %%F in ('dir /a:d /b /o:-d') do @rd /s /q "%%F"
etc..

md C:\Process2\%date:~6,4%_%date:~3,2%_%date:~0,2%
CD /D C:\Process2\
for /f "skip=%1 eol=: delims=" %%F in ('dir /a:d /b /o:-d') do @rd /s /q "%%F"
etc..
```

Its possible to find and get the paths where .log files are in, and make the actions in all them without putting the path directly on the batch?
We are creating more and more processes which generate logs on diferent paths, so I need to automate this.

Thank you

Comment: How to find the logs?

Comment: More exactly, get the path where logs are in. And then, make all actions on every path.

Comment: And what are **logs**?  How can I identify a log?

Comment: Is like a text (.txt) file, where processes information is written, is just the same, but with .log extension (for example process1.log)

Answer (score 0):

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
pushd C:\source\
set "LOG_PATH=;"

for /f %%L in ('dir /b /s  log_*.log 2^>^&1') do (
    ( ECHO !LOG_PATH!| FIND ";""%%~dpL"";") >nul 2>&1 ||set "LOG_PATH=!LOG_PATH!"%%~dpL";"
)
popd

echo ~~!LOG_PATH!~~
set "for=for /f "skip=%~1 eol=: delims=""

for %%A in (!LOG_PATH!) do (
  md %%A%date:~6,4%_%date:~3,2%_%date:~0,2%
  %for% %%F in ('dir /a:d /b /o:-d "%%A"') do @rd /s /q "%%F
)

endlocal
```

Comment: This conditions me to add a path everytime I create a process generating logs, and add the 70 paths I already have (70 processes). The way should be to find directories, something like `dir /b /s *.log` and pass paths to the for. It should be something like that?

Comment: Is there something common in log files names? Or root directory where they are located?

Comment: They are all in C:\source\ (but in different subfolders), all with .log extension, and all starts with log_ (log_xxx.log)

Comment: Thats very nice work. But the last "for" doesn't work (Change %1 with any number and will delete the oldest folders skipping the number of newest folders you want). Also when I try to create the folder with date on it, `md C:\source\Process1\%date:~6,4%_%date:~3,2%_%date:~0,2%` I use `md %LOG_PATH%\%date:~6,4%_%date:~3,2%_%date:~0,2%` but neither. I have also tested to clear all log files, and this works fine.

Comment: ahm.. Do you need more help here? If you have issues with `skip` parametrization you can use this `set skip=%~1 & for /f "eol=: delims=" %%F in ('dir /a:d /b /o:-d^|more +!skip!') do @rd /s /q "%%F"`

Comment: You'll need a valid number for %~1  - you want to skip one line or to pass it as an argument???